# Cannot change username on Gerrit, after changing github username

Tags: git, github, gerrit, review

I had github username "Old_UserName" and it worked well with gerrit, as in, I was able to commit and get a review.

On the gerrit website (review.openswitch.net) the username "Old_UserName" was automatically setup using github's credentials.

Everything worked fine, until I changed my username on github to "New_UserName". But on gerrit website (review.openswitch.net), I still see "Old_UserName".
Help appreciated.

I want to get things working, change of username is NOT that important, so I can even revert back to my old username if that's the only solution.

Here is the konsole output of the git review:

```
git review
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
remote:
remote: ERROR:  In commit 00blah000blah000blah000id000
remote: ERROR:  committer email address correct.email.address@domain.com
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  You have not registered any email addresses.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  To register an email address, please visit:
remote: ERROR:  https://review.openswitch.net/#/settings/contact
remote:
remote:
To ssh://Old_UserName@review.openswitch.net:9XXX1/openswitch/ops-build
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master (invalid committer)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://Old_UserName@review.openswitch.net:9XXX1/openswitch/ops-build'
```

I have tried to register the same email address again.
This email address was linked with it earlier too.
I get a verification email form gerrit. But, when I click on the verification link, it gives an "invalid token" error.

#### Constraints:

I cannot change my email id (since it's an organization email) or create a new git hub account for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update the username in the remote git config?

In .git/config in the project folder, switch the url of gerrit remote to reflect the new username:

```
[remote "gerrit"]
 url = Old_UserName@review.openswitch.net
```

to

```
[remote "gerrit"]
 url = New_UserName@review.openswitch.net
```

Comment: The issue was internally resolved though the organization by updating the database. Thanks anyways.